# Знаки вопроса вместо русского текста при получении sms

Tags: android, кодировка, sms

Знаю, что проблема не новая, но все же ответа не нашел!

Надо отправить меседж:

```
String txt = "Привет, " + name[i].toString() + ", бла бла чет руским текстом №" + numberOfOrder[i].toString();
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNum[i], null, text, null, null);
```

Но все что приходит это знаки вопроса "????????????".
Помогите решить проблему!

Answer (score 1):

Я с этим сталкивался в прошлом году, кажется.  Решение оказалось очень простым - `sendMultipartTextMessage`:

```
//String txt = "Привет, " + name[i].toString() + ", бла бла чет руским текстом №" + numberOfOrder[i].toString();
String txt = getString(R.string.sms_text, name[i].toString(), numberOfOrder[i].toString());
ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>(1);
parts.add(txt);
SmsManager.getDefault().sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNum[i], null, parts, null, null);
```

Comment: А стринги случайно в strings.xml выносить не надо?

Comment: Так тут же проблема на в том, что бы отправить много разных смс нескольким адресатам (это я в цикле задал прост, и оно работает себе), главный вопрос в том что текст _русскими буквами_ отображается не верно!

Comment: и все же видны толлько знаки вопроса. Думаю может проблема в том что когда программа считывает данные с текстового файла, она уже там как-то теряет кодировку. Считываю BufferReader'ом, далее запихиваю с массив стрингов.

Comment: Проверьте, что находится в строке прямо перед тем, как отправлять sms.

Comment: Дада, мой Toaster тоже ругается вопросиками.

Comment: @AleksG и еще, там сразу после чтения с файла, я забиваю данные в TextView и уже там имеются вопросы вместо текста.. может считывание неверно?

Comment: Ну так с этого нужно было начинать. Сначала нужно разобраться с чтением файла.